# Issue with materialized view refresh

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

We have two databases, one on 11g and the other on 10g. On 11g we have a few tables the data of which are copied over to 10g using materialized views and database links. So in short

Master table on 11g
Materialized view on 10g
Db link on 10g

The problem we are facing is that the materialized view refresh is not always working. MV refresh is not giving any errors. Its just that any change in data in the master table is not reflecting on the materialized view after refresh.

Comment: Was the job scheduled to run after the change?  Did the job run?  Are you certain that no errors were raised?  Either the refresh job was not scheduled to run or the job did not run or it ran and raised an error or when it ran the change to the master table was not yet committed.

Comment: @Justin here is the flow ... master table inert/update->commit->mv refresh... I am sure that no error was raised... I even tried the whole thing manually... in some cases new rows showed up after the first refresh, but in most of the cases it did not...

Comment: Do you use fast or complete refresh? On demand or scheduled? Do you have materialized view log on the 11g master table and use a fast refresh on the 10g replica mview?

Comment: We do complete refresh. Its on demand. And no we do noy have a lof on 11g master.

Comment: Sorry, tried my best to replicate your problem (from 12.1 EE to 11.2 XE), but with no success. Complete refresh via db link worked like charm. :-(

Comment: If the problem persists, I suggest that you turn on the extended SQL trace just for the problematic mview refresh and look into the trace file if you can come up with anything useful.

Comment: Thanks @nop77svk... I will try that... do you have any ideas how to debug it?